# How to make a string in quotes from integer in php?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

How to do make a string in quotes from integer in better way in php?

```
$number = 1;
$number = "'" . $number . "'";
```

result is '1', which is good, but can it be done more nicely? I tried `(string) $number` but result was just `1` not `'1'`.

Comment: What you are trying `echo $number;`? Yes if you try `Typecast` to `string` it will give you same `1`. **There is no special way to do this**. `$number = "'" . $number . "'";` is Good.

Comment: This is a strange question. If I `echo 'Hello string';` It also doesn't show the quotes, but that doesn't mean it isn't a string. And yes you can make it shorter `$number = "'$number'";`

Comment: @Manwal ok thanks, I need there thes quotes because mysql. I was just curious if there is not any usual way in php how to do it.

Comment: for faster interpreting with multiiple vars u schould use this instead; `$number = "'{$number}'";`

Answer (score 1):

$num = 1221;

echo $numStr = "'$num'";

Results: '1221'

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

$num = 1221;

echo $numStr = "'$num'"; // output: '1221'

var_dump($strVal); // output: string(4) "1221"

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.